# fulltext index does not index xml columns

Tags: sql-server, xml, full-text-search, sql-server-2019

We installed a new SQL Server 2019 Standard Edition Cluster (15.0.4298.1) on a Windows Server 2022 Datacenter-Cluster (20348.1547)

In some databases we use fulltext catalogs on xml columns.
But the fulltext service is not able to index the xml column.
Other columns with other datatypes work fine. So the fulltext service itself is working.

According to the documentation indexing of xml columns should just work.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/use-full-text-search-with-xml-columns?view=sql-server-ver16

On the previous SQL 2017 cluster it worked.

On an other SQL 2019 Developer Edition instance it also works as documented.

Changing the compat level to 140/2017 doesn't help.

In the SQLFT-Logfiles SQLFTxxxxx.LOG it says

```
Warning: No appropriate filter was found during full-text index population for table or indexed view '\[\_test\].\[dbo\].\[\_test\]' (table or indexed view ID '789577851', database ID '68'), full-text key value '11'. Some columns of the row were not indexed.
```

The message also appears in a newly created database.

The result from
`EXEC sp_help_fulltext_system_components 'filter';`
for .xml is. The path to the xmlfilt.dll file is correct and the file exists.

filter  .xml    41B9BE05-B3AF-460C-BF0B-2CDD44A093B1    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\xmlfilt.dll    12.0.9735.0 Microsoft Corporation

the SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher Service is running under this account: "NT Service\MSSQLFDLauncher"

there are no error or messages in the SQL Server error log or the windows application log.

here is my test-script

```
drop table if exists _test
go
create table _test (
  id int identity(1,1),
  XmlText xml,
  VCText  nvarchar(max),

  constraint [pk_test] primary key clustered([ID] asc)
)

insert into _test (XmlText,VCText) values('<weight>172</weight>','69')
insert into _test (XmlText,VCText) values('<t>test</t>','abc')

select * from _test

create fulltext catalog [test] with accent_sensitivity = off as default
go

create fulltext index on [dbo].[_test] key index pk_test on ([test]) with (change_tracking auto)
go
alter fulltext index on [dbo].[_test] add ([vctext])
go
alter fulltext index on [dbo].[_test] add ([xmltext])
go
alter fulltext index on [dbo].[_test] enable
GO

alter fulltext catalog [test] rebuild
go

-- query xml column -> no result
select * from _test
  where contains(XmlText,' "test" ')
  
-- query nvarchar(max) column -> result
select * from _test
  where contains(VCText,' "abc" ')

-- query the fulltext system catalogue
select * from sys.dm_fts_index_keywords(db_id(), object_id('_test'))  

| keyword            | display_term | column_id | document_count |
|----------------------------------------------------------------|
| 0x00360039         | 69           | 3         | 1              |
| 0x006100620063     | abc          | 3         | 1              |
| 0x006E006E00360039 | nn69         | 3         | 1              |
| 0xFF               | END OF FILE  | 3         | 2              |
```

I expect that there also should be the values "172" and "test" for column 2.

here are some other statements I have tried so far, but with no luck.

```
EXEC sp_fulltext_service @action='load_os_resources', @value=1;
EXEC sp_fulltext_service 'verify_signature', 0;
EXEC sp_fulltext_service 'update_languages';
Exec sp_fulltext_service 'ft_timeout', 600000;
Exec sp_fulltext_service 'ism_size',@value=16;
EXEC sp_fulltext_service 'restart_all_fdhosts';
EXEC sp_help_fulltext_system_components 'filter';
reconfigure with override
```

any ideas what is wrong with this SQL 2019 installation?

Comment: Check the filters that are installed : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/configure-and-manage-filters-for-search?view=sql-server-ver16#installed-filters

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. 
I have already checked the filters. There is a filter for .xml registered.
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\xmlfilt.dll 12.0.9735.0

Comment: That filter is for version 15 and you are using 2019.  You probably have more than one instance of the server loaded.

Comment: As far as I know 15 equals 2019. 
I'm very sure, that we only have one SQL Server instance installed on that box. 
The Developer instance also uses the xmlfilt.dll 12.0.9735.0 and there the fulltext works fine.
Meanwhile I also tried fulltext index with varbinary(max) columns. And that doesn't work either.

Comment: I would check to make sure your connection string is connecting to correct instance of server.  You can use SQL Server Management Studio to check the log file for the connection in the explorer under Management.  You are right about the versions : https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/?force_isolation=true

Comment: I'm connecting to the correct server. It is a problem inside of the sql instance.

Comment: Did you see following : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4649968b-3ae0-49f7-a53e-a89493d47970/adobe-pdf-ifilter-sql-server-2008-r2-full-text-not-working?forum=sqlsearch&force_isolation=true

Comment: Thanks for your help. 

Last night was a little longer than planned. I just wanted to fail over to the other node and test if this behaviour is also on the other node. But then CU19 was unintendedly installed. 

During this installation there were some error with the msdb and SSISDB. After I could solve these errrors and  successfully tested both nodes the full text search now works fine xml columns.

But the main reason, why the fulltext index did not work is still unknown :(